# How to query the complete latest row (not separately for each field) of data under different devices in one command of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to query the latest set of data records under each device at one time in Apache IoTDB? I know IoTDB can check the latest data using `last_value`, but the result coming back did not return the complete latest row of data, but only with the latest values of different fields. Therefore, I want to know if I want to check the entire row of data, how should I write my query statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `select last_value(*), MAX_TIME(*) from root.dc.* where time >= now() -1d align by device` statement in Apache IoTDB. There's no direct way to find the latest row of data, but can find the latest non-null value and the latest (maximum) time for each time series of the devices. See if this gives you all the information you need.